# .net executable cannot find libraries after it is signed

Tags: .net, f#

I have an F# console application. It is built using one long run of fsc, and works fine. (I am not using MSVS to build the application because it doesn't run under Mono, though the problem I am asking about happens under .net and Windows 7)

I thought I would sign the executable so it could be placed in the GAC. I added --keyfile to the compiler command line. Everything else is exactly the same. The .exe still builds fine, but dies at runtime complaining of being unable to find a dll that is still in the same place where it could see it just earlier.

I tried googling the answer without success. I expect there must be documentation explaining what to do? Many thanks for your help.

[The particular dll it complains about not being able to find is FsCheck, though it's probably just the first one it looks for. I imagine that signed assemblies need to depend only on signed dlls because they presumably need to be placed in the GAC too. I tried two different versions of FsCheck, one the latest available over NuGet. Neither was signed. I tried signing them using al, but it crashes (with segmentation fault under Cygwin)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that signed assemblies on the CLR can only reference other signed assemblies.  This means if you sign the exe all of the dll files it depends on must be signed as well.  It sounds like the assemblies available for it to find at runtime are not properly signed.  In order to fix this you'll need to sign those assemblies as well (possibly before you compile the exe)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to debug an issue like this is to fire up [`fuslogvw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will provide details on exactly where the CLR searched for dependencies, and why or why not those candidates were successful.

If you have VS installed, `fuslogvw` will be in the path if you start a developer command prompt.  If you don't have VS, you can get the tool by installing the Windows SDK.